# Spring security 3.1 new session not being created after login

Tags: jsf-2, spring-security

We are using spring security 3.1 with JSF and everything seems to be working except one thing that I was assuming was happening by default. 
I was expecting different session ids before login and after login but it is the same id in my case.
here is my configuration:

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<http auto-config="true" create-session="always" use-expressions="true" once-per-request="false" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">

    <intercept-url pattern="/blah/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <form-login  login-page="/loginpage.xhtml"
        default-target-url="/blah"
     />

    <session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession"/>
</http>


<ldap-server url="url" manager-dn="cn=blah.." manager-password="password"/>

<authentication-manager id="authenticationManager" alias="authenticationManager">
    <ldap-authentication-provider            
        user-search-filter="(uid={0})"           
        user-search-base="ou=Users"           
        group-search-filter="(uniqueMember={0})"           
        group-search-base="ou=groups"           
        group-role-attribute="cn"           
        role-prefix="none">         
    </ldap-authentication-provider>
    <ldap-authentication-provider            
        user-search-filter="(cn={0})"           
        user-search-base="ou=Users"           
        group-search-filter="(uniqueMember={0})"           
        group-search-base="ou=groups"           
        group-role-attribute="cn"           
        role-prefix="none">         
    </ldap-authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

I did not have this earlier, but adding it did not make any difference (tried newSession as well):

```
<session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession"/>
```

I also did not have

```
create-session="always"
```

and that is not making any difference either.

Can you help me figure out why a new session is not getting created?

Comment: If your Session is getting created as soon as you come to `Login` page then that session will carried through out the period you are acitve. Different session will get created once your current Session expires .

Comment: That makes sense without using spring security or turning session fixation protection off, but with session fixation protection enabled, from what I understand based on reading documentation, I would expect a new session to be created and information copied over from the existing session to address session fixation. That is the default behavior.